# What is the SpanStyle equivalent of RelativeSizeSpan?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

In Compose, we use `AnnotatedString` as a replacement for `Spanned`. However, I cant seem to find a way to replicate the behaviour of [RelativeSizeSpan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/RelativeSizeSpan) with a [SpanStyle](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/text/SpanStyle).

The relevant options I can see for `SpanStyle` are:

- fontSize: TextUnit - not useful because this only accepts absolute text sizes, and I need my span style to scale the original font size by some factor
- textGeometricTransform: TextGeometricTransform - not useful because `TextGeometricTransform` only performs X transformations, and I need the text to be scaled in both X and Y.

Can anyone share some insight?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve it with `SpanStyle`, but you need to use the `em` `TextUnit`, which is a relative font size unit. It means that *1em* is equal to the current font size and *2em* is a font two times bigger.

Here is the code demonstrating how it behaves on two `Texts` with different font size:

```
val annotatedString = buildAnnotatedString {
    append("This is a ")
    withStyle(style = SpanStyle(fontSize = 2.em)) {
        append("big")
    }
    append(" text")
}
Column {
    Text(annotatedString, fontSize = 20.sp)
    Text(annotatedString, fontSize = 40.sp)
}
```

The word **big** is 2 times bigger than other words in the same `Text`.
You can also see that it makes the **big** word from first `Text` the same size (*2 * 20sp*) as the other words in the second `Text` (*40sp*).

[image]